# Users getting a "This is probably not the site you are looking for" warning

Tags: ssl, https

Some users trying to visit my website are getting a warning explaining "This is probably not the site you are looking for".

One of them sent me a screenshot (I'm sure we've all seen this screen before at some stage):

[image: warning screenshot]

I'm using an SSL cert signed by StartSSL. It's signed for `shareshaper.com` and `www.shareshaper.com`.

You can see that the screenshot says that the user attempted to reach `www.wamrc.com`. I've never heard of that site before. For some reason though, when I visit `www.wamrc.com` I end up on my staging server.

I've tested my SSL setup with a number of online testing sites and they all report that everything is fine. I can't seem to replicate the issue myself.

What could be causing this error?

**Some Other Thoughts**

- I have another StartSSL certificate I use on my staging server. This one is valid for `staging.shareshaper.com` and (I assume, can't quite remember) `shareshaper.com`.
- One user who get the warning was using iPad Safari. Another OS X Chrome.
- wamrc.com [appears to belong to some dude called Oscar Arbelaez](http://whois.net/whois/wamrc.com).
- The issue was initially reported in [this Reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/Entrepreneur/comments/1uqw2l/uduckyfuzz_startup_diary_day_41_first_paying/cel4h7f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example it could be an incorrect DNS A-record for www.wamrc.com (pointing to your IP), or an incorrect cname for the same one, but all this is essentially included in the message in the screenshot.

Comment: Ah. I'm using Digital Ocean and I resized my server around the same time as I started getting this warning. I'm still on the same IP but I wonder if something got messed up in the resize.

Comment: Well, I thought about your IP first, but then it says that they tried to reach wamrc.com not your server, and landed at yours. This is what made me delete that part of the message...

Comment: Yeah I don't really understand that either. The user tells me that they were trying to visit `shareshaper.com` yet the screenshot shows them visiting `www.wamrc.com`.

Comment: It makes sense to check your `shareshaper.com` DNS records anyway, either do it yourself if Digital Ocean provides this functionality or ask them to check those for you if they do not. BTW, I just got to staging.shareshaper.com without issues (on SSL)

Comment: DO support got back to me. Oscar (the guy who owns wamrc.com) used to have the same IP as I'm using now and still has an A record pointing at it. Aparantly that's what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is misconfigured.  Its reporting itself as www.wamrc.com.

You need to talk to your hosting provider.